# Go can't find common and types package when building Geth client node project?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumj, golang, geth-debugging

I am trying to build the Ethereum Geth client node on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box.  I am using the 2017.3 Goland client.  When I try to compile the project I get the errors below:

```
interfaces.go:25:2: cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common (from $GOROOT)
    /home/robert/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common (from $GOPATH)
interfaces.go:26:2: cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types (from $GOROOT)
    /home/robert/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types
(from $GOPATH)
```

I have checked my GOPATH which has *go-ethereum* as its root.  I do see a *common* directory underneath it but not *types* directory.  I checked the Geth repo on GitHub:

https://github.com/ethereum

And I don't see a sibling *common* or **types** project.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You GOPATH directory is incorrect. This can happen only if you are putting your fingers into the sources. Normally if you untar and `make geth` you are not going to have this problem, as all the dependences are unpacked into `./vendor` directory and you don't need any GOPATH setting by hand. If you are doing a custom ethereum build then you should familiarize yourself with `Go`s directory structure, this is basic stuff in golang

Comment: download the Release tarball in the releases section and `make geth`, that's all you have to do

Comment: @Nulik I never touched the sources.  I simply cloned the repo and tried to build it with the Goland IDE.

Comment: then use the tarball,  master repo is the dev branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the setting of GOPATH is incorrect.

You need to set the GOPATH in the IDE to: `/home/robert/go` and then open the project via Open Directory to `/home/robert/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`.

See the [Go Workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) for how to set up a Go workspace.

Comment: @disniper That document you linked me "Go Workspace" is crucial.  Go is a picky about the directory structure it requires.  Once I changed my setup to match that indicated by the document, I could build successfully.  Thanks.

Comment: Being a newbie to Go, I'm wondering what the rationale is behind setting the package name in source as "github.com/.../...". What if the hosting website isn't determined at the time of coding? Wouldn't it be better if the source only needs to know the relative folder structure?